# Uncaught SyntaxError in html file but there are no identifiable syntax errors

Tags: javascript, html, electron

Getting a syntax error, but I can't see where the mistake is.

Error is: `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

The variable, `actions[i].command` that I am trying to reference is a string ex. `update:now`. It corresponds to an rpc event emitter. If i substitute the variable with a string it works as expected.

Here is the code snippet:

```
const actions = message.actions;
  for (let i = 0; i < actions.length; i++) {
    notiActions.innerHTML += `<a style="padding-left: 10px;" onclick="Emitter.send(${actions[i].command})">${actions[i].label}</a>`;
  }
```

I will note that I am not generally a fan of having html in javascript of vice versa.

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: Updated with the error

Comment: Also, instead of doing this, safer to do `actions.forEach(action => { let a = document.createElement("a"); a.className="..."; a.addEventListener("click", ...); a.textContent = action.label; notiActions.appendChild(a); })`, especially paying attention to the fact that you should not be setting `style` or using `onclick`. Use proper CSS classes, and don't use the mixed html+js1.0 `on...` attributes. Use modern JS.

Comment: Have you considered using the DOM API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) to do what you're doing here? Call `document.createElement` and then add the properties yourself before then appending to the `notiActions` element?

Comment: Couldn't get the click event to work using this method, but haven't put that much time behind it. Going to continue refactoring it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your "command" string is being injected into the JavaScript code of the event handler without any quote characters:

```
notiActions.innerHTML += `<a style="padding-left: 10px;" onclick="Emitter.send('${actions[i].command}')">${actions[i].label}</a>`;
```

As others have said, building HTML in JavaScript is never pretty and provides all sorts of breeding habitats for bugs.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. And I agree that html in javascript is never pretty and it usually isn't something that I normally permit. I'll look into the suggestions that others posted.